# Modify NSImage's pixel color

Tags: swift, macos, cgcontext, nsimage

I have some problem with modify NSImage's pixel color. What I'm doing is checking the pixel's color and change them.

Here is my code:

```
image.lockFocus()
    
guard let ctx = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {
    image.unlockFocus()
    return nil
}

// draw

guard let buffer = ctx.data else {
    return nil
}

let pixelBuffer = buffer.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: width * height)
let widthInPixelbuffer = ctx.bytesPerRow / (ctx.bitsPerPixel / ctx.bitsPerComponent)
let heightInPixelBuffer = ctx.height
let upperBound = Int(Float(heightInPixelBuffer) * 0.5)
        
for column in 0 ..< widthInPixelbuffer {
    for row in 1 ... upperBound {
        let offset = (upperBound - row) * widthInPixelbuffer + column
        if pixelBuffer[offset] == bgColor {
            break
        } else {
            pixelBuffer[offset] = 0xFFFFFF00 // yellow
        }
    }
}
image.unlockFocus()
```

My problem is that after I changed some pixel to yellow, what I see in the NSImage is transparent.(on my Mac book pro)

But it works fine on my Mac mini. I see the yellow color as expected.

I can't figure out it, could someone told me why?

How can I fixe it?

I have searched for this some days but I don't find the reason on the network.

thanks!

Comment: I can confirm your code does what you want it to do: I see only yellow replacing bgColor, no transparency. Are you running this code on your MacBook Pro, or are you saving the Mac mini output image to disk and copying it to the MacBook? Can you see other yellows on the MacBook?

Comment: hi @Loengard, thanks for your comment, I am running this code on my MacBook. But now I found the reason, on my mini, the cgContext from the NSImage is 32bits per pixel, and which is 64bits on my MacBook, but my code bind the pixel buffer to UInt32. So I need to create an CGContext manually and set it bit per pixel to 32 and It work fine on both mini and MacBook!